# How do I assign the argument of one of my functions as a variable name in R?

Tags: r, function

I wrote the following function:

```
rename.fun(rai,pred){
assign('pred',rai)
return(pred) }
```

I called it with the arguments `rename.fun(k2e,k2e_cat2)` and it returns the object I want but it is named `pred`.

The point of this function is to assign the object I define as `rai` to the object I define as `pred`. So rename `k2e` to `k2e_cat2`.

I am new to R but I am a SAS programmer. This is a very simple task with the SAS macro processor but I cant seem to figure it out in R

EDIT:

In SAS I would do the following:

```
%macro rename_fun(rai=) ;

data output (rename=(&rai.=&rai._cat2));
set input;
run;

%mend;
```

Essentially, I want to add the suffix _cat2 to a bunch of variables, but they need to be in a function call. I know this seems odd but its for a specific project at work. I am new to R so I apologize if this seems silly.

Comment: Don't  bring the logic of others programming languages. Any language has its own logic. I don't fully get what you are trying to accomplish, but very likely you don't need it. I also recommend to not use `assign` to anybody who hasn't a long experience in R. Please explain better the context and what you ultimately need.

Comment: why not just use `k2e_cat2 <- k2e` ?

Comment: There is no reason for doing this in R. R is not a macro language. How an object is named is irrelevant for (almost) any task and thus you don't need to rename objects.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Rob. Speaking as an experienced SAS programmer, the design of R is significantly different from SAS. The "R way of doing things" does not require a language that generates R code. Please explain what you're trying to accomplish with what in SAS would be called a macro variable, and we'll help you figure out how to do it in R. A minimal reproducible example in either R or SAS would also help. Also, there are situations where something that takes scores of lines of SAS code can be done in a single line of R.

Comment: Hi Len I edited my post as to what I would do in SAS. I am a complete R noob so any help is appreciated

Comment: So you want to rename objects by using a function which takes the new name and the object as input?

Comment: I saw your edit, but I'm still missing your goal. Why you want to change name to variables? Consider  @Roland's comment. Show more context, since it's very hard to see a case in which such renaming is indeed of any use.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I suspect you have some objects in the global environment that really should be together in a list instead. Then renaming would be extremely simple and you could also iterate over them if needed.

Comment: Seconding @Roland, I suggest you read up on how to use lists and the `apply` family in `R`.

Comment: Since you say you have several variables you want to add the same suffix to in a `data.frame` you could try something like: `add_suffix_cat2 <- function(df, vars){
  names(df)[match(vars, names(df))] <- paste0(vars, "_cat2")
  return(df)
}` And then you might call it like
`mydf <- mtcars;
res <- add_suffix_cat2(mydf, c("hp","mpg"));`

Comment: @MikeH.this helps me alot thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that you want to rename several columns in a `data.frame` you could simple do this by using a function that takes a `data.frame` and a list of column names to rename:

```
add_suffix_cat2 <- function(df, vars){ 
                      names(df)[match(vars, names(df))] <- paste0(vars, "_cat2") 
                      return(df) 
                   }
```

Then you can call the function like:

```
mydf <- mtcars
res <- add_suffix_cat2(mydf, c("hp","mpg"))
```

If you wanted to make the suffix customizable that's simlpe enough to do by adding another parameter to the function.